# Where do I find the header files for C on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: c, macos

Where do I find the header files for C on OSX Mountain Lion?

A few articles on the web say they are in `/usr/include` but when I `cd` to `/usr` there is no `include` folder!

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean Mac OSX.

Comment: You need to install Xcode and the CLT (Command Line Tools) first - they are not installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

From Paul R's comment:
"You need to install Xcode and the CLT (Command Line Tools) first - they are not installed by default."

---

So first download Xcode from App Store. Once you have Xcode.app, install the command line tools it includes.

Only then are the headers available in their default locations. (/usr/include)

Comment: Is this answer still valid on Mac OS X 10.11?  My command-line tools are installed (`cc -v` prints out info about LLVM and clang) yet there is no `include` folder under `usr`.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason you also need to run `xcode-select --install` to make the headers & libraries available in /usr/include and /usr/lib.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a working solution to install the include/ directory which contain the headers that you are looking for (Mojave 10.14.6 - Xcode 10.3), just run :

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Comment: This worked for me. Prior to finding your answer, I tried the xcode-select --install, which did install ok, but the include files didn't appear at /usr/include